# ¿Como realizar negación en if de javascript?

Tags: javascript, condiciones

tengo un problema al realizar una negación al usar una condición IF en javascript, no se si la sintaxis estará mal:

```
var correo = document.getElementById("email").value; 
var nom = document.getElementsByName("ciudad")[0].value;
var rs = document.getElementsByName("pais")[0].value;
var tel = document.getElementsByName("mensaje")[0].value;
if (!((correo == "")) || (!((nom == "")) || (!((rs == "")) || (!((tel == "")) {  //COMPRUEBO CAMPOS VACÍOS
alert("mensaje al no estar vacíos");
return true;
```

Comment: Te falta el cierre `}`

Comment: La sintaxis que ocupas para verificar `!((correo == ""))` pueda ser asi tambien: `(correo !== "")`

Comment: @FranciscoJavier gracias, también realice esa prueba y funciona correctamente! mi sintaxis estaba mal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si quieres comprobar que alguno de los campos está vacío

```javascript
if ( correo == "" || nom == "" || rs == "" || tel == "")
```

Si quieres comprobar que TODOS los campos estén vacíos

```javascript
if ( correo == "" && nom == "" && rs == "" && tel == "")
```

Si quieres comprobar que TODOS los campos estén completos

```javascript
if ( !(correo == "" || nom == "" || rs == "" || tel == "") )
```

Aunque te recomiendo utilizar la función `isEmpty()` en vez de `x == ""`

Comment: gracias por tu aporte, lo que quería era validar que estaban completos los campos o llenos los campos. Y funciono correctamente.

Comment: Me alegra que te funcionase. Recuerda que cuando niegas un **or** se convierte en un **and** y viceversa.